# hugo not generating the appropiate files when compiling website

Tags: hugo

so I'm having this issue where whenever I run the `hugo` command, only part of my website gets generated. I don't have empty files, they all have some content within. I would like to note that the specific section that isn't getting compiled is the faq section. any suggestions as to how I may fix this?

[Site Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1bNA.png)

[Generated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIfKc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was caused by hugo not recognizing the layout. Although I haven't found a way to fix it, I somewhat patched it by using the default layout for the page given that I had layouts for all other pages.